# No Sound card detected in Sound Settings, although sound works

Tags: pulseaudio, system-settings

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my laptop. When I go to **Sound Settings** while logged into my user, no sound card appears detected.

In spite of this, the sound on my laptop is working ok, and I can use `alsamixer` just fine. The Unity sound indicator is dead, and this is quite annoying.

If I login as guest, the sound indicator works just fine, I assume it's something related to my user's sound settings, but I cannot find what exactly.

Any clues?

Comment: If sound is coming in guest account, the sound card is already detected

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my MacBook Pro 8.1 running Ubuntu 12.04. I solved it by resetting pulseaudio user configuration as explained [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio).

You have to run the following lines in terminal

```
rm -r ~/.pulse*; pulseaudio -k
```

and then logout and log back in.

Comment: I got this message on running above mentioned command `rm: cannot remove .pulse*': No such file or directory
`

Comment: try `.config/pulse` instead of `.pulse`

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the problem that, You cannot select sound profile from the sound settings menu, then you can try the following method. I provided the answer in some questions. It works for me, so can also work for you.

---

### Solution 1:

*(It worked for me with Only S/PDIF profile, Sound from both headphone and speaker and not being able to switch profile)*

1. Add this ppa by the command

   ```
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
   ```
2. Update packages list by

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Then install "alsa-hda-dkms" package:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install alsa-hda-dkms
   ```

Reboot, And See the result!

---

### Solution 2

1. Go to [Realtek official site](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false), accept the disclaimer, then download the audio driver for linux/unix. You need to select version 3 for Kernel 3 or later.
2. Setup necessary tools to compile this driver.

   `sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc make`
3. Extract the downloaded file, run `sudo ./install` file from a terminal after going to the extracted folder to compile the driver.
4. Read the `Readme.txt` file for more information.

I had a problem with Sound settings in Ubuntu 12.04 (*not being able to switch profile*). It fixed now.

Comment: Solution 2 : Now I can't see my card in sound settings :(

Comment: the realtek drivers site no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with 12.10 and looked all over.  I finally found my answer here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/864735

I modified `/etc/default/grub`, rebooted and voila!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for contributing this answer!  It's generally helpful to quote the most relevant parts of a link (in this case, the instructions on the modification to make to `/etc/default/grub`) in case the target site is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Dell Latitude E4310 laptop) the problem was the following line in /etc/pulse/client.conf:

```
autospawn = no
```

I commented this out, and then ran

```
pulseaudio -k
```

and

```
pulseaudio
```

and then the sound icon in the taskbar came back to life, and the volume up/down/mute buttons started working.

Answer (score -2):

Install `pulseaudio-module-udev`

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-udev
```

Comment: Why do you suggest it? Please do not post "it worked for me".

Comment: -1 That won't help. The PulseAudio setup is already working in the guest account, so installing another package won't change anything.