# Integrated graphics HDMI audio devices are missing

Tags: sound, intel, hdmi, asus

I have just bought a new computer to use as an HTPC with Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, but I can't get HDMI audio to work. I am using the integrated graphics in an Intel i3-2120 CPU and the motherboard is an ASUS P8H61-M LX2. The TV is connected to the motherboard's DVI-D port via an HDMI-to-DVI cable. Video works perfectly, but in ALSA and PulseAudio I don't see any option to select HDMI audio output. e.g.:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: VT1708S Digital [VT1708S Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: VT1708S HP [VT1708S HP]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Other people that use integrated graphics and HDMI audio seem to have one or more "INTEL HDMI" devices listed, but I don't, and none of the above produce sound over the HDMI cable. I've tried playing with alsamixer, the sound settings, pavucontrol, HDA Analyzer, and the BIOS, but so far nothing has worked. Help!

My full alsa-info.sh output is at http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=96647290482cf72674c26fe9088b785116325737

Comment: [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/155392/61218) worked for me with no sound profile. That might help you also.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, alsa-hda-dkms didn't change anything for me. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually concluded that in my case this was probably a hardware issue. The P8H61-M LX2 motherboard probably does not have a chipset capable of routing audio to the graphics controller.

EDIT: Years later after upgrading to 14.04.3 I discovered that the HDMI audio devices had magically appeared, so it was an OS issue after all.

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct if it solves the problem.